# Can someone guide me through this error?

Tags: android, google-maps, io, split

The method is about to convert a string coming from another method which read from a file. The target of this method is to draw some points(which was read from a file) on a google map. I tried to split my string coming from the `readTheFile()`, and i get something like this: `latLng[0] = 68.43752735570531,17.433074489235878` and `latLng[1] = 68.43879697044444,17.436143271625042`. The string: `latLngString = "68.43752735570531,17.433074489235878\n68.43879697044444,17.436143271625042\n"` . The problem is that i simply can't get a proper split? or is it the best way to do this?- My two methods: -Any help is very appreciate-Thanks-
method read from file:

```
private String readFromFile() {
  File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
              File file = new File(path, fileName);
              String line = "";
              StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                  try {
                      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            text.append(line); // + '\n');
                            text.append("\n");
                        }
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.w("I/O exception" + file, e);
                    }
                    return text.toString();
                }
```

draw points from file:

```
private void drawPointsFromFile() {
   String latLngString = readFromFile();
   String[] latLng = latLngString.split("\n", 2);
   for (int  i = 0; i < latLng.length; i++) {
   Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latLng[0]), longitude = Double.parseDouble(latLng[1]);
   map = ((MapFragment) this.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
     map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
         .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
         .title("Lat: " + latitude + "," + " Lng: " + longitude)
         .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.myicon)));
            }
        }
```

Comment: you need to split above string and get lat and longs seperatly ??

Comment: i know that. I tried to split the string (exp: .split(",")), but it does works just for one point. If i have  several points it doesn't work. I dont know how to split correctly: from "68.43752735570531,17.433074489235878\n68.43879697044444,17.436143271625042\n" to 68.43752735570531,17.433074489235878 so then it becomes latLng[0] = 68.43752735570531 and latLng[1] = 17.433074489235878 foe the first point and so on..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this ,

```
    String string = "68.43752735570531,17.433074489235878\n68.43879697044444,17.436143271625042\n";

   // replace "\n" with ","
    String replacedString = string.replace("\n", ",");

  //split by ","
    String points[]= replacedString.split(",");

 //every odd indexs will be lats and even indexes will be longs
```

Then you can seperate lats and longs into seperate lists as follows, I assume first value is latitude and second is longitude.

```
    List<String> lats = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> lons = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length ; i++) 
    { 
        if(i % 2 == 0)
        {
            lons.add(points[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            lats.add(points[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried your idea, but it works just for one point. i have several points in my file (10 points).  String latLngString = readFromFile().replace("\n", ",");  String[] latLngReplaced = latLngString.split(","); and for (int  i = 0; i < latLngReplaced.length; i++) {
     Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latLngReplaced[0]), longitude = Double.parseDouble(latLngReplaced[1]); }

Comment: sorry, there was a mistake, i have edit the answer, try again

Comment: it's the same answer, i don't see the difference? Maybe the problem is here:  for (int  i = 0; i < latLngReplaced.length; i++) {
            Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latLngReplaced[i]), longitude = Double.parseDouble(latLngReplaced[i+1]);} and not 0 and 1, but it dosen't work with i and i + 1?

Comment: just try, its not same answer dude , there was a big mistake, try and comment if the issue is still there

Comment: sorry, but i'm getting the same issue, just the first point? here what i did: String latLngString = readFromFile().replace("\n", ",");  and then String[] latLngReplaced = latLngString.split(","); so  for (int  i = 0; i < latLngReplaced.length; i++) { Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latLngReplaced[0]), longitude = Double.parseDouble(latLngReplaced[1]); }

Comment: i have format the looping, try and see weather it suits for your requirement

Comment: i got just the first point because [0] and [1], but if i change to [i] and [i+1] i get a crash!

Comment: you cant access the element in that way, see what i have done and try according to that

Comment: debug and see where your string is getting null

Comment: Thanks for your help i appreciate it very much -i cleared a little here and there- & it works like a charm now. I have understood much better.